How to set text boxes in a PowerPoint slide to appear and disappear after a set time for each of them
I have 3 text boxes in a PowerPoint slide. I want them to be appeared and disappeared automatically based on the timing.
TextBox-1:

Appear: At the beginning of the slide shows up.
Disappear: Never until the next slide comes up.

TextBox-2:

Appear: At the beginning of the slide shows up, meaning with the TextBox-1.
Disappear: After 20 seconds

TextBox-3:

Appear: Right after the TextBox-2 disappers
Disappear: After 30 seconds

I played with the animation by adding entrance and exit animation but could not achieve this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Text box 1:  just put it on the slide so it appears when the slide appears. No animation needed.
Text box 2: Add an appear animation set to With Previous. Then choose Add Animation and choose an exit animation. Set it to After Previous and set the delay to 20 seconds (might want to set it to something shorter for test purposes).
Text box 3: Same thing; setting it to With Previous will keep it hidden until text box 2 has appeared and done its thing.

Sigh. Some mornings it's just not worth chewing through the leather straps.  -- E. Phillips
